# Windows 7 high CPU and HDD load

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu-usage, svchost

Constant Windows 7 high CPU and HDD load. Process Explorer shows following 2 **svchost** processes doing this:

[image]

One of them contains following services:

[image]

Another contains this services:

[image]

Any way to prevent them doing this? Stop or setup some services?

---

Comment: install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx also works for win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO** and click on **Start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage and DiskIO. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB fodler) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and pist the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: Not yet, while installing WPT forced to reboot, problem gone, will wait for next cause to reproduce and send the trace here asap.

Comment: WPRUI disabled some "Paging Executive" and forced me to reboot again. Will wait for next cause.

Comment: yes, this is required to capture callstacks. This setting is enabled by default starting with Win8.

Comment: Could be some planned tasks? Any way to review and disable?

Comment: I need to take a look at the trace to see which activity you have.

Comment: Uploaded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hegce3ury8zyv0t/ASUS-PC.03-07-2016.22-27-38.etl.NGENPDB.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high CPU usage is mainly caused by 4 process (2 x svchost.exe, googletalkplugin.exe and Skype.exe).

[image]

The first svchost.exe process tries to load driver Inf files (`SPInf.dll!SpInfLoadInfFile`). This activity is caused by `googletalkplugin.exe` which enumerates audio devices (`devenum.dll!CCreateSwEnum::CreateClassEnumerator`) and tell Windows to read the inf data and this also causes the CPU usage of the 2nd svchost.exe. Here the Windows audio service detects new audio devices (`audiosrv.dll!CAvEndpointBuilder::OnDeviceInterfaceArrival`)  and tries to enum and activate them (`MMDevAPI.dll!CDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints / MMDevAPI.dll!CEndpointDevice::Activate`).

So the root cause seams to be `googletalkplugin.exe`, look if there is an update for it.

Comment: Uninstalled it completely as unnecessary for now, will check if issue gone.

Comment: Issue started again today, new log attached: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e9yztgb1sejpf6/ASUS-PC.03-21-2016.23-29-10.etl.NGENPDB.zip?dl=0

Comment: Even restart does not fix this, please help.

Comment: the callstacks are the same, so a different tool triggered that Audio card enumeration activity. But I can't really see which.

Comment: Could You say me which card? I'll try to find new drivers for it or even disable.

Comment: run WPRUI.exe, load and check this profile inside WPRUI.exe (**Add Profiles**) (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rl4r784kvnhypf/Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP?dl=1) click on Start. This captures also extra audio events.

Comment: also if you don't need the audio support of the GPU (audio over HDMI), disable them because I guess you only use the VIA one most of the time.

Comment: Error on loading profile: "Every user-defined profile file should contain profile definitions for both the logging modes File and Memory". Should I just enable "Audio Glitches"?

Comment: I've disabled all sound cards except VIA: CPU and HDD load reduced significantly however issue still exist. Could be old drivers for VIA and C-Media cards. HDMI Nvidia seems worked fine previously, before I'd installed VIA drivers (card was not working previously).

Comment: yeah, it could be a via driver issue. Try other drivers: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&func=select&id=208&orderby=2&page=1&lang=en

Comment: No sound at all with these drivers, will revert to driver came with motherboard.

Comment: Driver with motherboard: VIA HD Audio Codec Driver  v7.9.00.32.100211
Your driver: Via HD Audio Codec Drivers Version 6.0.11.0100 (11.1.00.30.130816), so will need to find something in between.

Comment: Installed the latest driver from here: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=startdown&id=2045&lang=en - seems works fine, also the latest Nvidia Audio drivers for HDMI. Will see if problem appear again. Sometimes it appear after computer wake up after sleep.